# Json.NET TypeNameHandling and TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I hope you can help me to understand how `TypeNameHandling` and `TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling` settings in Json.NET work.

## Scenario

Suppose to have these entities:

```
namespace SerDesTest
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public int Int0 { get; set; }
        public string String0 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Father : BaseClass
    {
        public Father() { Children = new List<BaseClass>(); }

        public List<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : BaseClass
    {
        public Child(Father father) { Father = father; }

        public Father Father { get; set; }
        public int Int1 { get; set; }
        public string String1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Generic<T>
    {
        public int GenericInt { get; set; }
        public string GenericString { get; set; }
        public T GenericProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And to use the following helper methods:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            SerializationBinder = new JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder()
            {
                KnownTypes = GetTypeList("SerDesTest")
            }
        });
    }

    public static TEntity Deserialize<TEntity>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            SerializationBinder = new JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder()
            {
                KnownTypes = GetTypeList("SerDesTest")
            }
        });
    }

    public static IList<Type> GetTypeList(string assemblyName)
    {
        List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), $"{assemblyName}.dll"));

        if (assembly != null)
        {
            list.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes());
        }
        return list.AsParallel().Distinct().ToList<Type>();
    }
}
```

To run it the following:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Father father = new Father();
            Generic<Child> generic = new Generic<Child>
            {
                GenericInt = 100,
                GenericString = "100",
                GenericProperty = new Child(father)
                {
                    Int0 = 0,
                    Int1 = 1,
                    String0 = "0",
                    String1 = "1"
                }
            };

            string genericJson = JsonHelper.Serialize(generic);

            Console.WriteLine(genericJson);

            Generic<Child> genericDes = JsonHelper.Deserialize<Generic<Child>>(genericJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

## Running the test program

When running the test program, I obtain the following json:

```
{
  "$type": "Generic`1",
  "GenericInt": 100,
  "GenericString": "100",
  "GenericProperty": {
    "$type": "Child",
    "Father": {
      "$type": "Father",
      "Children": [],
      "Int0": 0,
      "String0": null
    },
    "Int1": 1,
    "String1": "1",
    "Int0": 0,
    "String0": "0"
  }
}
```

and the following exception:

> Type specified in JSON 'SerDesTest.Generic`1, SerDesTest,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not
>   compatible with 'SerDesTest.Generic`1[[SerDesTest.Child, SerDesTest,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], SerDesTest,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path '$type',
>   line 2, position 22.

## Questions

I have two questions/problems:

1) Due to the Json.NET configuration, my expectation in line 2 of json is to have the "full qualified name" for the `$type` field, something like: **"$type": "SerDesTest.Generic[SerDesTest,CHild]"** and not only **"$type": "Generic`1"**...

2) Have you any idea about solving the exception?

Thank you,
Attilio

### Update 1

As requested by Brian Rogers, following the code for `JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder`:

```
public class JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public IList<Type> KnownTypes { get; set; }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return KnownTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = serializedType.Name;
    }
}
```

### Update 2

Some more tests. If I don't set the `SerializationBinder` I use this version of `JsonHelper` class:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            //SerializationBinder = new JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder()
            //{
            //    KnownTypes = GetTypeList("SerDesTest")
            //}
        });
    }

    public static TEntity Deserialize<TEntity>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            //SerializationBinder = new JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder()
            //{
            //    KnownTypes = GetTypeList("SerDesTest")
            //}
        });
    }
}
```

I solve all my problems: first I have no exception in deserialization process; second I have the following json as output:

```
{
  "$type": "SerDesTest.Generic`1[[SerDesTest.Child, SerDesTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], SerDesTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "GenericInt": 100,
  "GenericString": "100",
  "GenericProperty": {
    "$type": "SerDesTest.Child, SerDesTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "Father": {
      "$type": "SerDesTest.Father, SerDesTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Children": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SerDesTest.BaseClass, SerDesTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
        "$values": []
      },
      "Int0": 0,
      "String0": null
    },
    "Int1": 1,
    "String1": "1",
    "Int0": 0,
    "String0": "0"
  }
}
```

You can play with `TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling` option to tune the information contained in the `$Type` field.

So the question becomes: how can I implement the `ISerializationBinder` interface to get a more secure software?

Comment: @BrianRogers done. Thank you

Comment: `GetTypeList` returns an open type definition (no types specified) of your `SerDesTest` class whereas your excepts the `GetTypeList` a close type definition (as the error states):  `SerDesTest<SerDesTest.Child>`.

Answer (score 0):

To have the "full qualified name" for the $type field, change `JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder` in **Update 1** to set the assembly name in the `BindToType` & `BindToName` methods as shown below

```
public class JsonManagerKnownTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public IList<Type> KnownTypes { get; set; }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return KnownTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName && t.Assembly.GetName().Name == assemblyName);
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = serializedType.Assembly.GetName().Name;
        typeName = serializedType.FullName;
    }
}
```